# Can't access models from crystal play

Tags: crystal-lang

How do I access models from Crystal Play? After installing Crystal and the Amber framework I am unable to access my new model, User from Crystal Play. I am able to start the project using 'crystal watch' and save a new user using the auto-generated views.

```
# Steps to reproduce
amber new test
amber g scaffold users fname:string lname:string  active:boolean
amber db create migrate # DB was created and app does start.
amber play

# Navigate to http://127.0.0.1:8080
u = User.new # Error: Undefined constant User
u = user.new # Error: undefined local variable or method user
u = Users.new # Error: Undefined constant Users
u = users.new # Error: undefined local variable or method users
```

Crystal 0.27.0 [c9d1eef8f] (2018-11-01)

LLVM: 4.0.0

Default target: x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu

Amber CLI (amberframework.org) - v0.11.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use the application I had to include the application code at the top of the interactive console.

```
require "./config/*"
```